# difference between Mage::app and Mage:: in Magento

Tags: magento

Can any body say what is the difference between 
Mage:app and Mage::

eg:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

Mage::app->getLayout->createBlock('catalog/product_view');
```

if i try like this

```
Mage::app->getModel('catalog/product');
```

it throws a fatal error

What is the basic difference?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As a more general explanation and further to Alan's answer `Mage::app()` and `Mage::getModel()` are both static methods of the Mage class (`app/Mage.php`).

The `Mage::app()` function is used to bootstrap your Magento application (setting up configuration, autoloading etc) and is useful when wanting to access Magento models in your own custom script for example.

It is a static method so it can also be called at any point in your application to return the current Mage_Core_Model_App object which you can use for example to get current configuration values e.g. `Mage::app()->getStore()` will return the current `Mage_Core_Model_Store` store object.

`Mage::app()` is similar to `Mage::run()` found in your `index.php` file. The difference is that `Mage::run()` will amongst other things also invoke the MVC, routing etc part of your application as per default and control the request/response directing you to a page and instantiating the blocks and layout template rendering.

`Mage::getModel()` is simply a factory method that will return a new instance of a class based on the class alias you provide. For example `Mage::getModel('customer/customer')` will return a new `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` object. If you want the same object back each time throughout your request you can use `Mage::getSingleton()` instead.

Comment: I hope official documentation were so detailed

Answer (score 12):

When you say

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
```

You're calling the static method `getModel` on the class Mage

```
#File: app/Mage.php
public static function getModel($modelClass = '', $arguments = array())
{
    return self::getConfig()->getModelInstance($modelClass, $arguments);
}
```

When you say

```
Mage::app->getModel('catalog/product');
```

you're going to get a fatal error, because that's invalid PHP.

However, if you say

```
$app = Mage::app();
```

You're calling the static method `app` on the `Mage` class

```
public static function app($code = '', $type = 'store', $options = array())
{
    if (null === self::$_app) {
        self::$_app = new Mage_Core_Model_App();
        self::setRoot();
        self::$_events = new Varien_Event_Collection();
        self::$_config = new Mage_Core_Model_Config();

        Varien_Profiler::start('self::app::init');
        self::$_app->init($code, $type, $options);
        Varien_Profiler::stop('self::app::init');
        self::$_app->loadAreaPart(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_GLOBAL, Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::PART_EVENTS);
    }
    return self::$_app;
}
```

which will return a `Mage_Core_Model_App` object, which will let you call any method on the class/object at

```
app/code/core/Mage/Model/App.php
```

Comment: so app() and getModel() are static methods belonging to the class Mage.Am i correct?